# Fancybox inline flash issue with Firefox

Tags: flash, fancybox

I have a number of [fancyboxes](http://fancybox.net) on a page (one in each repeateritem) which show inline flash when a button in the appropriate repeater is pressed.

In Internet Explorer the fancyboxes open correctly and show the inline flash.

However in Firefox when opening they open the inline flash in a new tab??
Anyone experienced this issue?

-- Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually managed to get it working.

Not entirely sure how but here are some steps i did..

- Stopped using AC_RunActiveContent.js
- Stopped doing client side concatenation and writes i.e. `document.write('<object>....</object')`
- Instead, (in my case) relied on databinding the changing variable the flash file needed.
- Made the inline flash code as close to the [FancyBox inline flash example](http://fancybox.net/example) as possible

That is..

```
<object width="560" height="340">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/M-cIjPOJdFM&hl=en&fs=1&"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/M-cIjPOJdFM&hl=en&fs=1&" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        allowscriptaccess="always" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        width="560" 
        height="340">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Yeah! Yeah! Yeah! Working!!.

-- Lee